# How to add taxonomy term image related to node in panel?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

How to add taxonomy term image related to node in panel?

I am displaying node details , where in I want to show the image taxonomy term related to that node in the Panel. I did add context relationship and selected taxonomy term image in panel content but it is not showing up?